# Can't get phone contacts (B4A)

Tags: android, contacts, vb4android

I need to get the phone number of a contact by name; I'm using B4A (B4XPages).
So I tried ContactUtils and wmContactUtils libs, and also by content resolver, with the official sample of coded; I did not get any error or exception, but I did not get any contacts.
I checked for permissions.
I've the same iusse on 3 different phones (android 8.1, 11 and 13); I also done phone reset.
I did not posted here the code since I used the official samples without any change, but I will if can help.

Comment: Check Permissions: Ensure that you have the necessary permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file to access contacts. The required permission is `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS`. Make sure you have added this permission in your manifest.

Comment: It's the first thing I've checked, and I have android.permission.READ_CONTACTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a boolean property to show only visible contacts or all; setting it to true I get the contacts.